# CloudFormation serverless function stack Error - Error occurred while GetObject. S3 Error Code: NoSuchKey

Tags: aws-lambda, yaml, aws-cloudformation, aws-serverless

I'm trying to create a stack based on this project: https://github.com/aws-samples/duomfa-with-amazon-cognito.

As my region is different I need to create a bucket and upload the functions.

[image]

And in my yaml I have this :

```
  DefineAuthChallenge:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-DefineAuthChallenge
      Role: !GetAtt LambdaExecutionRole.Arn
      CodeUri: s3://bucket-name/DefineAuthChallenge
      Handler: index.handler
      Runtime: nodejs12.x
      MemorySize: 1024
      Timeout: 30
      Tracing: Active
```

but the stack is not created and I have this error :

Resource handler returned message: "Error occurred while GetObject. S3 Error Code: NoSuchKey. S3 Error Message: The specified key does not exist. (Service: Lambda, Status Code: 400, Request ID: fcf29d84-0bd5-4459-9505-c63faee7bfce, Extended Request ID: null)" (RequestToken: 53f3365e-b858-33c3-8b5c-42dfdf6e41b7, HandlerErrorCode: InvalidRequest)

Am I missing something ?

Comment: Are you sure that `s3://bucket-name/DefineAuthChallenge` is the correct path?

Comment: Yes but I found the issue, I needed to add the file extension .zip ahah